# i got error "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: serviceType"

Tags: nopcommerce

I was following a tutorial , but after setting the project build path, I run the project and navigate to plugins. Then I got the following error.
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code,

> "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: serviceType"

and i don't know that which method i should add and in which class?

Please help!

Comment: Which type of plugin are you developing?

Answer (score 2):

you must register the service you created in the plugin and also the repository for your entity in DependencyRegistrar.cs file so that run time Autofac can found them for example:

```
public class DependencyRegistrar : IDependencyRegistrar
{
    public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder)
    {
        //data context
        this.RegisterPluginDataContext<MYPLUGINObjectContext>(builder, "nop_object_context_misc_MYPLUGIN");

        //override required repository with our custom context
        builder.RegisterType<EfRepository<ENTITY>>()
            .As<IRepository<ENTITY>>()
            .WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IDbContext>("nop_object_context_misc_MYPLUGIN"))
            .InstancePerHttpRequest();
    }

    public int Order
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}
```